# Regex replace url with links

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a little help with some regex I have. Basically I have a shout box that only shows text. I would like to replace urls with links and image urls with the image. I've got the basics working, it just when I try to name a link that I have problems, well if there is more than one link... check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/wYC52/).

Named link format `{name}:url` should become `<a href="url">name</a>`. The problem I am having is with shout #5 where the regex doesn't split the two urls properly.

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li>Shout #1 and a link to google: http://www.google.com</li>
 <li>Shout #2 with an image: http://i201.photobucket.com/albums/aa236/Mottie1/SMRT.jpg</li>
 <li>Shout #3 with two links: http://www.google.com and http://www.yahoo.com</li>
 <li>Shout #4 with named link: {google}:http://www.google.com</li>
 <li>Shout #5 with two named links: {google}:http://www.google.com and {yahoo}:http://www.yahoo.com and {google}:http://www.google.com</li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
var rex1 = /(\{(.+)\}:)?(http\:\/\/[\w\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:\/\S*)?(?:[\w])+)/g,
  rex2 = /(http\:\/\/[\w\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:\/\S*)?(?:[\w])+\.(?:jpg|png|gif|jpeg|bmp))/g;

 $('ul li').each(function(i){
  var shout = $(this);
  shout.html(function(i,h){
   var p = h.split(rex1),
    img = h.match(rex2),
    typ = (p[2] !== '') ? '<a href="$3">$2</a>' : '<a href="$3">link</a>';
   if (img !== null) {
    shout.addClass('shoutWithImage')
    typ = '<img src="' + img + '" alt="" />';
   }
   return h.replace(rex1, typ);
  });
 });
```

---

**Update:** I figured it out thanks to Brad helping me with the regex. In case anyone needs it, here is the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Qf5Xm/7/) and code (Now works in IE!!):

```
var rex1 = /(\{(.+?)\}:)?(http:\/\/[\w\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:\/\S*)?(?:[\w])+)/g,
rex2 = /(http:\/\/[\w\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:\/\S*)?(?:[\w])+\.(?:jpg|png|gif|jpeg|bmp))/g;

$('ul li').each(function(i) {
  var shout = $(this);
  shout.html(function(i, h) {
    var txt, url = h.split(' '),
    img = h.match(rex2);
    if (img !== null) {
      shout.addClass('shoutWithImage');
      $.each(img, function(i, image) {
        h = h.replace(image, '<img src="' + image + '"  alt=""  />');
      });
    } else {
      $.each(url, function(i, u) {
        if (rex1.test(u)) {
          txt = u.split(':')[0] || ' ';
          if (txt.indexOf('{') >= 0) {
            u = u.replace(txt + ':', '');
            txt = txt.replace(/[\{\}]/g, '');
          } else {
            txt = '';
          }
          url[i] = '<a href="' + u + '">' + ((txt == '') ? 'link' : txt) + '</a>';
        }
      });
      h = url.join(' ');
    }
    return h;
  });
});
```

Comment: One of your problems is that URL is not delimited by anything. This would make your regexp extremely complex, as it now has to understand the format of URL. Even if you restrict yourself to http:, it's still tough.

Comment: @Arkadiy: I can't control what people type into the shout box =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\{(.+?)\}:)
```

you need the `?` to make the regex become "ungreedy" and not just find the next brace.

**EDIT**

However, if you remove the `{yahoo}:` the second link becomes null too (seems to populate the anchor tag, just no attribute within). This almost seems to be a victim of using a split instead of a replace. I would almost recommend doing a once-over looking for links first, then go back around looking for images (I don't see any harm in off-linking directly to the image, unless that's not a desired result?)

Comment: +1 Thanks... you got me on the right track, but yeah I see the problem.

Comment: I got it, thanks!... I just added a couple of loops to break the links apart. I updated my demo above :)

Comment: @Brad Christie: Hmm, any clue why IE totally messes up on the first regex? When I put an alert inside the `$.each(url...`, the value of `u` never contains a url, only the text around it.

Comment: As per http://jsfiddle.net/Qf5Xm/1/ it doesn't seem to be just IE, FF (atleast Beta 4) isn't doing so hot either. Let me get a few more sips in to my coffee and I'll give it a go. ;-)

Comment: With a bit further research it appears it may be linked to this: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split (though I'm still looking in to it). I even tried making my own regex and it's behaving differently, so I'm thinking it's how IE handles it.

Comment: Yeah very odd. Thanks for the link - I had no idea about the problems with split. And I can't look at your jsfiddle link because for some odd reason the site is down.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it again LOL... I split the string with a space instead of the regex and the problem went away - I still had to modify the code a bit more, but I also fixed the problem I was having if two links were exactly the same. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Heh, glad to help. That was my next venture; to split in to "Words" then compare against image or link url. But looks like you figured it out. Awesome! *EDIT* p.s., wouldn't it be easier to just check for link then use a \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ check to look for image urls? (you already know it's a uri, why compare further?)