# How do I extract a URL from plain text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm a beginner with jQuery.

I simply want to pass a block of text to a function and return an array of urls contained within.

"I need to grab a url like http://www.something.com from text, and if therearemore.com then grab those too".

Any help? Is there a .GetUrl()?

Note: I suck with regular expressions!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Extract URL from Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189124/jquery-extract-url-from-text)

Comment: This has more to do with Javascript the language than jQuery the library.

Comment: I also asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308732/regex-replace-url-with-links

Comment: fudgey's is way over my head. I get it but I'm still blocking on applying it...

Answer (score 30):

The jQuery Wiki Text plugin (http://www.kajabity.com/jquery-wikitext/) includes Regular Expressions to find URls in text which can be used for the purpose.

So, you asked for a function - well here it is:

```
/**
 * A utility function to find all URLs - FTP, HTTP(S) and Email - in a text string
 * and return them in an array.  Note, the URLs returned are exactly as found in the text.
 * 
 * @param text
 *            the text to be searched.
 * @return an array of URLs.
 */
function findUrls( text )
{
    var source = (text || '').toString();
    var urlArray = [];
    var url;
    var matchArray;

    // Regular expression to find FTP, HTTP(S) and email URLs.
    var regexToken = /(((ftp|https?):\/\/)[\-\w@:%_\+.~#?,&\/\/=]+)|((mailto:)?[_.\w-]+@([\w][\w\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/g;

    // Iterate through any URLs in the text.
    while( (matchArray = regexToken.exec( source )) !== null )
    {
        var token = matchArray[0];
        urlArray.push( token );
    }

    return urlArray;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: really bad answer.  Never, _ever_, _ever_ attempt to guess what a legal domain-name is using a regexp.

Comment: @Alnitak which is your proposal?

Answer (score 7):

RegExp is probably the way to go, and this should do the trick for you:

```
var searchText = $('yourElement').text(),

    // urls will be an array of URL matches
    urls = searchText.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})\b/ig);

// you can then iterate through urls
for (var i = 0, il = urls.length; i < il; i++) {
    // do whatever with urls[i]
}
```

[**See demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/gd7kR/1/)

Comment: really bad answer.  Never, _ever_, _ever_ attempt to guess what a legal domain-name is using a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a regular expression. Try:

```
/\i\b(http|https):\/\/(\S*)\b/i
```

If you aren't good with regular expression, I'd recommend taking a look at this online tool for building them: http://rubular.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get all type of links

http://aaa.aaa.aaa

www.aaa.aaa

www.aaa.aaa/aaa

string.match(/(www|http|https|ftp|ftps)?:?/?/?[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?/gi);