# How to add an anchor tag to a URL in a String

Tags: jquery, string, anchor

I've got a few strings which contain youtube links (different lenghts and positions in the string, not every string contains an URL) and text. These strings will be written into paragraph-tags but i want the URLs to be clickable, so i need anchor tags around the URL.

I managed to find a way to access the paragraph which contains a link:

```
if($("#facebookFeed p:contains('http')").length){
    //do stuff
}
```

I'm stuck here and not sure if thats the right way to do it.

Comment: For starters, there's no such thing as a perfect URL regex, but you can plug in a 'pretty good' one that will pick out URL's more reliably

Comment: @darkpbj Speaking of "the perfect URL regex", I've liked using this - http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use regex to match the URLs within the string, and then wrap them in an anchor:

```
$('p:contains("http://")').html(function(index, html) {
    var url = html.match(/(((ftp|https?):\/\/)[\-\w@:%_\+.~#?,&\/\/=]+)|((mailto:)?[_.\w-]+@([\w][\w\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/g);

    $.each(url, function(i, v) {
        html = html.replace(v, '<a href="' + v + '">' + v + '</a>');        
    });

    return html;
});
```

*The example above uses the regex pattern found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504853/how-do-i-extract-a-url-from-plain-text-using-jquery#answer-5997959)*

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/623Sd/)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you testing for `ftp`? I didn't think anchors would work for them.

Comment: @admdrew I used a regex pattern found in another answer (lazy I know), I just wanted to demonstrate how to replace the matches with anchors.

Comment: Please edit so that 'var url = html.match(/(((ftp|https?):\/\/)[\-\w@:%_\+.~#?,&\/\/=]+)|((mailto:)?[_.\w-]+@([\w][\w\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/g) || []' so url would never be null but instead a blank array. An error pops up whenever the html var does not contain any valid url's.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do

```
$("#facebookFeed p:contains('http')").each(function() {
    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="' + $(this).text() + '"/>');
});
```

As demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/uyHQ2/

Ofcourse, this assumes a certain HTML layout.
If yours is different, then please post an example of the HTML.

Comment: This is the right answer, I hope the OP figures that out.

Comment: the whole string is written into the paragraph. my strings look like this: "randomtext http://www.youtube.com/... randomtext". So Martijns function creates: `<a>randomtext http://www.youtube.com/... randomtext</a>`. What I need is: `randomtext <a>http://www.youtube.com/...</a> randomtext`