# How to select text that contains particular letters

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` that contains paragraphs elements with text inside. Sometimes this text can be a link which I want to store in a var. I only want to select the link text, not the paragraph and not the div.

So here is an example of the HTML

```
<div>
  <p>I have found a good review of a TV here <br>
    https://www.avforums.com <!-- I want to select this text ---> <br> 
    This seems good to me! 
    </p>
</div>
```

If I do this:

```
if ( $("div:contains('http')") ||  $("div:contains('www')") ) {
var extractedLink = // select the link text and store it here
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to select just the link text - it ends up selecting the entire `<p>` or `<div>`. The rules of a link are that it either begins with http or www and it has no spaces in it whatsoever. So I want to select just the string that contains http or www that has to spaces in it.

It sounds simple but I'm stuck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504853/how-do-i-extract-a-url-from-plain-text-using-jquery   .. and about if statement  use  $("div > p:contains('http')")

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links

Answer (score 2):

Since you already able to select the entire `<p>` or `<div>`, how about split the text within it and test them one by one?

```
var sentences = $(???).text().split(" ");
for (var i...) {
    var sentence = sentences[i];
    if (sentence.substr(0, 4) == "http" || ...) {
        // found!
    }
}
```

Or,

You can try [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with regular expression. It will return an array of matched strings.

```
var str = "http://www www.www www.x www.google.com/www_hey are a famous website while http is not"
matches = str.match(/(\bhttp|\bwww)\S+/gi);
// matches = ["http://www", "www.www", "www.x", "www.google.com/www_hey"]
```